# Ionic 3 Caching issues when used in browser

Tags: angular, cordova, caching, ionic-framework, ionic3

we are developing an app with Ionic 3.7.1 currently using the Cordova browser platform (amongst ios). When I deploy a new version to our web server, I regularly get caching issues: buttons not working, black screen etc.

Errors are `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: r.ngOnDestroy is not a function` or `Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't[n].call')` in `vendor.js` and similar.

I know it's a caching issue because if I disable or clean cache, it starts working again.

I have already attached hash codes to the main files like main.js, vendor.js, polyfill.js, and main.css. But maybe it has to do with Ionic's/Angular's lazy loading of more scripts like build/17.js.

Any tips of what causes this or how to influence the behavior? What does Ionic 3 do in terms of caching?

Any help would be highly appreciated as I am really stuck here!

Comment: This is a constant headache for me and my clients. cleaning cache for all their customers every time we release is just not an option.

Comment: Did you solved this issue?

Comment: @KevinRED Yes, I did. We used a combination of AppCache (a deprecated mechanism, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache) and Service Workers (the new standard which allows better control over caching, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers).

Comment: @user3181425 Could you please provide more details?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem that OP. Could you provide more details about your fix?

Comment: what exactly do you want to know?